# How to make MVC dropdownlist change editor field value

Tags: c#, razor, model-view-controller

I have an edit view that implements a normal editor text field. The user can manually enter a value that can be saved to the model. However, alongside this editor field I also need a dropdownlist that the user can select from that will edit the editor field. However, the value I am putting in the editor field is not the same as the value selected from the dropdownlist, this value comes from another list which uses the index of the item selected by the dropdownlist to put the value. To illustrate:

I have a text field "Name Id" and and two lists "Name" and "Id". The user will select a "Name" and the view will place the "Id" into the "Name Id" Field.

Example:

Name Id: 2   <----- 2 was entered because Bob was selected

Name:

1. Alex
2. Bob
3. Carl
4. Dennis

Answer (score 0):

> Note: Don't forget to include JQuery reference for js code.

Razor Code:

```
    @{
    var domainsList = new SelectList(new []
    {
        new SelectListItem { Text = "Please Select", Value = "0", Selected = true },
        new SelectListItem { Text = "Alex", Value = "1" },
        new SelectListItem { Text = "Bob", Value = "2"},
        new SelectListItem { Text = "Carl", Value = "3"},
        new SelectListItem { Text = "Dennis", Value = "4"}
    }, "Value", "Text");
}
    @Html.Editor("NameId", new {@class="form-control"})
    @Html.DropDownList("Nameslst", domainsList,new {@class="form-control"})
```

Js Code

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('#Nameslst').on('change',function(){
            $('#NameId').val($(this).val())
        })
    })
</script>
```